# Why when painting one source to another am i getting the wrong colors

Tags: cairo, pycairo

When I try the following I expect the two images to be the same but they are not!
I'm new to this cairo thing and this is driving me mad.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cairo

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 256, 256

pat = cairo.LinearGradient (0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0)
pat.add_color_stop_rgb (1,    1,   0,  0) # First stop
pat.add_color_stop_rgb (0.5,  0,   1,  0) # Mid stop
pat.add_color_stop_rgb (0,    0,   0,  1) # Last stop

# A surface

surface0 = cairo.ImageSurface (cairo.FORMAT_RGB24, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx0 = cairo.Context (surface0)
ctx0.scale (WIDTH, HEIGHT)

ctx0.set_source(pat)
ctx0.paint()

# My second surface

surface1 = cairo.ImageSurface (cairo.FORMAT_RGB24, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx1 = cairo.Context (surface1)
ctx1.scale (WIDTH, HEIGHT) 

ctx1.set_source_surface(surface0, 0, 0)
ctx1.set_operator (cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
ctx1.paint()


surface0.write_to_png("example0.png")
surface1.write_to_png("example1.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do:

- Create a pattern called `pat`
- Paint that pattern to `surface0` with some scale
- Copy `surface0` to `surface1`

Right?

In this case you should remove the call `ctx1.scale (WIDTH, HEIGHT)`. Due to that, you will only get the top-left pixel(?) of the first surface drawn to the second one.

Comment: Thank you. That explains exactly what I am seeing. I've been finding the scaling and transforms a bit confusing, but I think I get it now.